# Does Setting search_path Block In Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, postgresql-9.6, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to debug high contention of `LWLock:lock_manager` in Amazon Aurora Postgres 9.6. It looks like this:

[image]

This happens during when I try to setup a new schema for a new user. I lock a central table (`SELECT 1 FROM main_schema.schemas WHERE where Id = userId FOR UPDATE`). This should lock only that row. I do this new setup which can take 20-40 seconds (mostly in a big transaction, adds 3 dozen tables and dozens of indexes/fks). However, for that 20-40 seconds most traffic to Aurora starts hanging on `lock_manager` when other queries try to call `SET LOCAL search_path` in their own transactions to their own schemas, shown below:

[image]

This is the `search_path` I set on other users during other traffic:

`SET LOCAL search_path TO sub_schema_{x}, extensions;`

As a result, there are a few thousands roles.

Note: Amazon/Postgres explains `lock_manager` as code that just observes or waits to examine backend for locks. It is not a specific read or write lock it seems.

Dozens of these queries seem to hang. My questions:

1. Does setting LOCAL `search_path` somehow acquires a lock on something?
2. What other locks can cause this sort of contention?

Comment: Perhaps Amazon broke something when they hacked up PostgreSQL, but in PostgreSQL no locks are taken when `search_path` is set. Certainly not since commit [880bfc3287d](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=880bfc3287dd68cfe90d10d9597d7b0fd2dae3e5) from 2012-04-11.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've been looking through stuff, and by the end of the provisioning, before the commit there are > 700 locks being held at a time (on new tables mostly). Since lock_manager does not indicate that a specific lock is being waited on, perhaps this amount is too great for the lock_manager to handle in a timely manner with other traffic going on? Is 700 locks a lot for Postgres at a single time?

Comment: Not necessarily, no. If you run out of lock space, you get a hard error, not a hang.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this.

This process happened during provisioning of a new customer. System creates a new schema & tables and a new role that has permission to access that schema. The new role inherits from a base role (not a super role).

By this point we had about 8,000 schemas and 8,000 roles. It seems past 4,000, and much more by 6,000 new roles, every time you create a role and have decent traffic going to your instance, it has to refresh some background tables and causes locks like this (on the first query). Once the system was adjusted to use a single role, the issues went away.

Reading Postgres forums and mailing list, it seems the role portion of Postgres is poorly optimized and might cause issues if there is a lot of roles or inheritance.